# Prove that an evolute of a plane curve is a helix.

Tags: differential-geometry

I have seen someone use this solution but I think it's wrong since they're proving using an example. 

 It starts with: evolute of the function $\alpha$$(t)= (cost, sint, t)$ let's first find the curvature:

Let $k(t)= $$\frac{||\alpha'(t)x\alpha''(t)||}{||\alpha'(t)||^3},$

then i'll proceed to find the curvature above. then also finding $N(t)$ (which is $B(t) x T(t)$ ) so i'll find $T(t)$ and $B(t)$ next. to get $N(t)$

is this solution on the right track or is it wrong? please help me, i'd greatly appreciate it. thank you.

Comment: You want to show that the *involute* of the helix is a plane curve, so you need the Frenet frame and curvature of the helix, yes.

Comment: No. You have it backwards.

Comment: Read what I wrote.

Comment: @TedShifrin I got it!! thank you so much! but could you tell me why would they use the function $\alpha(t)= (cost, sint, t)$?

Comment: That's one parameterisation of the helix. There's a pretty neat visualisation of it, and how the Frenet frame moves around.

Comment: @mizh thank you so much for your time!